# PHP Soap request works in cli but not in browser

Tags: php, curl, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are making soap request to microsoft exchange server 2016. Request from cli scripts and soap clients are working. Same script with same request xml won't work when called from browser.

```
class testClass extends SoapClient {

    public $user = 'username';
    public $password = 'password';

        function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = NULL) {

        $headers = array(
            'Method: POST',
            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
            'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
            'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            'SOAPAction: "'.$action.'"',
        );

        $this->__last_request_headers = $headers;


        $request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                      <soap:Body>
                        <DeleteItem DeleteType="HardDelete"  SendMeetingCancellations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                          <ItemIds>
                            <t:ItemId Id="AAANAG9wQHRmaHMubHUuc2UARgAAAAAAoeCyBeBA7EGXcncI4cCeZwcAnd+iJ87BLkGneeHHldhNdAAAABB5VAAAnd+iJ87BLkGneeHHldhNdAAA1wzUcAAA"/>
                          </ItemIds>
                        </DeleteItem>
                      </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>';

        $ch = curl_init($location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->user.':'.$this->password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.json');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.json');

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if(!trim($response) == "")
            return $response;
        else
            return "no resp";
unlink("cookies.json");
    }
}


$result = $client->DeleteItem($DeleteItem);
var_dump($result);
```

We have checked and made sure that we have openssl, curl, soapclient extensions.
We are getting the following error when requesting from browser.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wsdl2phpgenerator\xmltfhs\test.php:140 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wsdl2phpgenerator\xmltfhs\test.php(140): SoapClient->__call('DeleteItem', Array) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wsdl2phpgenerator\xmltfhs\test.php(140): testClass->DeleteItem(Object(DeleteItemType)) #2 {main} 
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wsdl2phpgenerator\xmltfhs\test.php on line 140
```

Comment: Which server are you using? apache, nginx or iis?

Comment: Apache. It would be grateful if you could help.

Comment: Could this be a file permission issue?  You may be running the script as a different user in each case.  Try a tmp folder that's world writeable for cookies.json.

Comment: Thank you @Progrock your answer helped.

Comment: @Progrock You can add the answer. As you mentioned in the comment I created a folder for cookies.json and gave world write file permission and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to file permission issue. I added the cookies.json file in a tmp folder and gave it world writable permission and changed the cookies.json path in the SoapClient Class.